# How do I get the value of a BoundField in a django template?

Tags: django, django-forms

The built in as_html, as_ul, as_p methods on Django forms don't work for me, nor does the built in `{{field}}` rendering, so I'm trying to write a custom form rendering.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    <input id="id_{{field.html_name}}" 
                   type="text"
                   name="{{field.html_name}}"
                   placeholder="{{field.label}}"  <!-- "placeholder" is really the only reason I need to do a custom implementation -->
                   value="{{ XXX }}"      <!-- what goes here? -->
                   maxlength="30"  />
```

The question is, what should go in the value attribute (marked `XXX` above)?

I've done some looking around and it doesn't appear that `BoundField` supports a `value` or `data` attribute.  I'm using ModelForms if it matters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `value` attribute landed in trunk [in 2010](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10427). The patch shows how to retrieve the value using the form/data (not simple in a template unfortunately). There are some template tag code snippets in the ticket comments you may find useful.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the field name is "username" and the form name is "user_form", there are two values:

1) Initial:

```
{{ user_form.initial.username }}
```

2) Bound:

```
{{ user_form.username.data }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to find an answer for this question for several hours. The above answer didn't help me.

I found the solution here:
http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2264/

You need to add new directory: /yourproject/yourapp/templatetags/

In /yourproject/yourapp/templatetags/ place 2 files:

__init__.py - empty file

field_value.py - with the following code:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def field_value(field):
    """ returns field value """
    return field.form.initial.get(field.name, '')
```

At the beginning of your template you nedd to add:

```
{% load field_value %}
```

Where you want to output a value of a field you need to add:

```
{% field_value form.field %}
```

Or if you already have a "field" variable, then just:

```
{% field_value field %}
```

For me it was a field with name "text" of an inline form, so I added the following code

```
{% field_value inline_admin_form.form.text %}
```